How to record database User permission changes
How can I record changes to a database User permissions?
I have a SQL Server 2019 database user that loses Select permission overnight, but we do not know why.  I want to audit or record those changes.  xEvents does not seem to have such an Event. Various AI chat tools recommend sqlserver.database_permission_change, sqlserver.database_permissions_changed, and sqlserver.security_policy_add_permission, but those don't actually exist.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/find-permission-changes-in-the-default-trace

One thing you might want ot check is if the schema owners change. In this case permissions can be lost and I believe this isn't tracked anywhere (but is documented)

DDL trigger on database can log it for you
